# Excel - count unique values with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique, frequency, countif

I am having an issue with counting unique values in a range based on multiple criteria. I've used the following array formula to count how many IDs (col C) have a value in col I between 17 and 18:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(('Refined event data'!$I$2:$I$1500>=17)*('Refined event data'!$I$2:$I$1500<=18),'Refined event data'!$C$2:$C$1500),'Refined event data'!$C$2:$C$1500)>0))
```

However, when I use an advanced filter to extract the data manually and perform a standard countifs formula, I receive a different result.

There are blanks in both ranges, and all the data in the ranges are formula results, although this does not seem to matter as I get the same discrepancy when all the data is pasted as values and blanks excluded.

Any help as to why the difference in the two methods is occurring would be much appreciated.
Cheers,
Ant

Comment: This might now be solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61939342/9758194)