# Excel - Count unique values that meets multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, office365, unique

I have 5 columns:

Quarter, Item, Type, Count,  Date

I am trying to pull a UNIQUE count of date for each Quarter & Item combination
ie. FY20Q3-AU has 2 different dates, FW20Q3-GLW has 1 unique date, FY20Q3-GLE also has only 1 unique date

Does anyone have any idea how I can accomplish this? I have been trying for a few hours modifying formulas that I found online without success.

If possible, I am trying to do this without an array formula (not sure if that is even possible)

I have tried:

```
{=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A:A=A2,MATCH(B:B,B:B,0)),ROW(B:B)-ROW(B2)+1)>0))}
```

---

```
| Quarter | Pricelist | Change Type | Item Count | Date    |
|---------|-----------|-------------|------------|---------|
| FY20Q3  | AU        | Type 1      | 1          | 4/18/20 |
| FY20Q3  | AU        | Type 1      | 1220       | 4/4/20  |
| FY20Q3  | CH        | Type 2      | 2          | 4/11/20 |
| FY20Q3  | CH        | Type 1      | 1378       | 4/4/20  |
| FY20Q3  | GLA       | Type 1      | 1          | 4/18/20 |
| FY20Q3  | GLA       | Type 1      | 1421       | 4/4/20  |
| FY20Q3  | GLB       | Type 1      | 1250       | 4/4/20  |
| FY20Q3  | GLB       | Type 2      | 1          | 4/4/20  |
| FY20Q3  | GLC       | Type 1      | 1          | 4/18/20 |
| FY20Q3  | GLC       | Type 1      | 1404       | 4/4/20  |
| FY20Q3  | GLH       | Type 2      | 2          | 4/11/20 |
| FY20Q3  | GLH       | Type 1      | 1387       | 4/4/20  |
| FY20Q3  | GLME      | Type 1      | 1          | 4/18/20 |
| FY20Q3  | GLME      | Type 1      | 1421       | 4/4/20  |
| FY20Q3  | GLEE      | Type 1      | 1          | 4/18/20 |
| FY20Q3  | GLEE      | Type 1      | 1227       | 4/4/20  |
| FY20Q3  | GLEU      | Type 1      | 1          | 4/18/20 |
| FY20Q3  | GLO       | Type 1      | 211        | 4/4/20  |
| FY20Q3  | GLK       | Type 1      | 1          | 4/18/20 |
| FY20Q3  | GLC       | Type 1      | 1          | 4/18/20 |
| FY20Q3  | GLW       | Type 1      | 1          | 4/18/20 |
| FY20Q3  | GLU       | Type 1      | 1          | 4/18/20 |
| FY20Q3  | GLZ       | Type 1      | 1          | 4/18/20 |
| FY20Q3  | JP        | Type 1      | 1          | 4/18/20 |
| FY20Q3  | NHI       | Type 1      | 1          | 4/18/20 |
| FY20Q3  | NHI       | Type 1      | 1          | 4/18/20 |
| FY20Q3  | WCH       | Type 2      | 2          | 4/11/20 |
| FY20Q3  | WCH       | Type 2      | 2          | 4/11/20 |
```

Comment: @JvdV 16.37 on Mac (also have the windows version of needed)

Comment: @JvdV yeah, i believe so

Comment: @JvdV So i tried to do that, and this is what I hve, but it is not working and just showing 1 by each column: =COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(E:E,COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)=0)))

Comment: @JvdV sorry I have updated with the request

Comment: @JvdV oh my gosh -- you just saved me so much time with this! I would have never figured this out. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @JvdV of course :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So since you got access to O365 and it's DA-functions you would not need a CSE entered formula nomore. You can utilize `UNIQUE` and `FILTER`. For example:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(E:E,(A:A=A2)*(B:B=B2))))
```

Where I would suggest you won't use whole column references to not break down performance too much.

Comment: The only note on this method is that FILTER will return `#CALC` error when none match the criteria and COUNTA will count this as `1` and not `0`  In this instance that the OP wants unique dates we can use `COUNT` to not count the error.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner. I guess since we check for values always included in the lookuprange this would not be a concern perse.

Comment: True, for this instance.  I will leave the comment for future users, who may be testing criteria outside the dataset.