# Finding a more efficient way of using SUM PRODUCT and COUNTIF

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, unique, criteria

I currently have this formula which works but it takes a few seconds for excel to catch up, and I was wondering if anyone knew about a more efficient way of handling this.  Aside for it taking a few seconds to process when I drag the formula down excel doesn't update the new cells and eventually crashes the entire file.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((Paste!$B$2:$B$12000=A2))/COUNTIFS(Paste!$B$2:$B$12000,Paste!$B$2:$B$12000&"",Paste!$C$2:$C$12000,Paste!$C$2:$C$12000&""))
```

Sample Data: 
[image]

Comment: Some sample data and expected output could yield more positive results than just the current formula.

Comment: @JvdV I have added some sample data, please note my actual sheet contains many more processes and input/output are on different sheets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's imagine the data layed out in front of us as you present:

---

[image]

---

**1)** Formulas Without DA-functionality:

You could apply [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-with-criteria) method:

In `F3`:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A$3:A$9=E3,MATCH(B$3:B$9,B$3:B$9,0)),ROW(B$3:B$9)-2)>0))
```

Enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

**2)** With DA-functionality

You could apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61939342/9758194) method:

In `F3`:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(B3:B9,A3:A9=A2)))
```

Adapt any of the above to fit your ranges and needs, but do remember array formula may just way heavily on calculation.

---

**3)** Pivot Table:

If you want to avoid formulas alltogether, simply select all your data e.g. `A2:B9` and follow these steps:

- Click tab `Insert` from the ribbon and choose `PivotTable`
- Choose where to insert the resulting table and check *"Add this data to the Data Model"*
- Use *"Process"* as column, and *"Test_ID"* as values.
- Go to *"Value Field Settings"* and summarize values by *"Distinct Count"*
- Confirm and enjoy the resulting table:

[image]

Comment: nvm - figured it out. This is awesome!