# Count of number of unique customers by month

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a spreadsheet that contains data for customers that have purchased items from my store.  What I would like to do is go back the last couple years, using a pivot table, and display: number of customers that ordered something each month (a count of unique customer names).

The sheet is organized as such:

```
Date     | Invoice | Account Name     | Item            | Quantity | Amount
6/1/2020 | 50100   | John's Tire Shop | 1/2 Inch Socket | 2        | 12.00
```

Is there a way inside pivot table options to count unique account names and display the total grouped by month?

Comment: I should say that I feel like I'm close to a solution, but need help.  In the pivot table, under the "Values" section, I've added a "Count of CustomerName" which counts every customer... is there a "Unique Count" option somewhere?

Comment: Yes there is a unique count option. Let me [share a link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62202292/9758194) with you. See if using the option "Add this data to the Data Model" opens new opportunities. GL

Comment: In Value Field Settings, I'm not seeing a "Distinct Count" option, just a Count or Count Numbers.

Comment: Then you didn't follow what I described in the given link.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper column to identify unique values per month to add as a filter to your pivot using your existing setup

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,B2)=1,"y","n")
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would propose you to add a helper column to your data, containing the `=Month(A:A)` function. But be careful: I see that your first date equals "6/1/2020", is that the first of June or is this Epiphany? :-)